# What is the difference between "service" and "component"?

Tags: c#

I am little bit confused about the difference between a service and component. Can someone explain with example that what is the difference between a service and component?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A service can be made up of several components. Usually a service provides one complete feature that is made up by combining different components.

The service's user don't need to know anything about the underlying components. User will deal only directly with the service while service internally will be interacting with the components

Answer (score 4):

**Services** are applications that are (generally) designed to be long running, tied to the operations of the system rather than a user and provide a utility to other applications. Databases, SMTP, Active Directory are all examples of "Services".

**Components** are pre-formed pieces that can be included in other applications and are not designed to operate 'on their own'. An application that references a database my use a data component (SQLClient) to communicate with a date base service (MS SQL Server).

Comment: callies:+1 for the answer...If I am wrong correct me...You want to say that "service is self business functionality"

Comment: @geek, I am not sure what you mean. A service provides a class of functionality (like data, mail, authentication) across a business, or a network. Most every machine is going to be running a multitude of service (Network Client, DHCP, TCP/IP, etc.) even if the role of that machine is to host a particular service (like say a SQL server runs all of these services in support of the principal services (MS SQL, SQL Agent,SQL Browser...) and more..)

Answer (score 0):

services have only provide interface that allow to access the functionality of service and also they are used remotely using some mechanism of message communication model like Remote Procedure call
where as Components have both Provide and require interface to communicate with the other component in order to perform the intended functionality and they are used locally

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Services are designed with reusability in mind; a service can be made by combining different components together. But the idea is that when one service fails in a microservice (i.e., an entire system), it won't affect the running of other services in that system. They are designed to be self-sustaining.

For components, they are designed to fit into an application, and their effectiveness largely depends on the whole system working as well, but they are also reusable.